# Android: Fragment cannot get activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which does a fragment transaction

```
DetailFragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.mylist, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

that works fine. Now I know within my activity a dynamic string I need to replace in the layout I have in newFragment. I thought that I can call after transaction.commit() just something like

```
newFragment.setMyString("my dynamic value");
```

And in the newFragment.java I have

```
public void setMyString(String s)
{
 TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myobject);
 tv.setText(s);
}
```

The point is that getActivity() returns null. How can I get the context I need to find my layout elements?

**Edit:**

I try to follow the route using a bundle as this seems to be the cleanest way. So I have changed my code:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("text", "my dynamic Text");
DetailFragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();
transaction.replace(R.id.mylist, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

My fragment onCreateView looks like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
   TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.texttobereplaced);
   t.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text");
}
```

It seems that savedInstranceState is empty.  Where should I find my bundle?

**Edit2:**

missed the getArguments() in the reply. is working now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `Fragment` hasn't attached to the `Activity` yet, which also means your layout hasn't been inflated yet (See the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)). The best solution here would be to add your `String` value as an argument to the `Fragment` via the [`Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. This can be retrieved in the receiving `Fragment` via the [`Fragment.getArguments()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29) method.

Comment: My layout is inflated onViewCreated is called. I can see my layout.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you call `getActivity()` in or after `onAttach()`, as before then it will return `null`.

Comment: sorry I don't understand where I shall call getActivity() and pass it to my setMyString() function. And if I do it where you suggest you still write it may or may not return null. How shall I understand this?

Comment: The `Fragment` will be attached to a `null` activity until `onActivityCreated`... that is, if you call `getActivity()` in `onCreate` or `onCreateView`, it will return `null` because the `Activity` hasn't been created yet. So make sure you have all of your calls to `getActivity()` *in or after* `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: This is wrong. Once onAttach is called getActivity() can be called without it returning null. onActivityCreated is just a callback for when the activity was fully created and the fragment's layout has been instantiated.

Comment: @AlexLockwood  Why do you state it will return null in onCreate()?  I see plenty of examples in Android framework where they call getActivity() inside of onCreate().  Here is one example: http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/packages/apps/Calendar/src/com/android/calendar/QuickResponseSettings.java

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I wrote that... the activity should be available as long as you call `getActivity()` after `onAttach()`. I edited my original response to address this... and to be honest, I'm not sure how this answer got 5 upvotes. I guess I was more of a noob 2 years back. :P

Answer (score 2):

So i am also using the same fragment transaction manager and the only problem i can see with your code is that you define the TextView tv inside your onCreateView method of your newFragment class and then instantiate it as like this :

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newFragment, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        return v;
    }

    public void setMyString(String s) {
        tv.setText(s);
    }
}
```

I know it does'nt make really much sense but that is how i am running my code and it works fine :)

Comment: sorry did'nt know it was that important :) changed it ..hopefully looks better now

Comment: Of course indenting your code is important on StackOverflow... people aren't going to think you are a very credible source if your code is blatantly unreadable. I just edited your answer and removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

if u need to call getActivity in OnCreateView, move all ur code from onCreateView to onActivityCreate and only left lines

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxx, container, false);
    return v;
```

in onCreateView

but i have a funny situation.

in My onActivityCreated

```
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bitlength);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.bitlengths,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Sometime the onActivityCreated wont run (correctly!?) and hence the spinner s1 become empty.